# To what reading level does a specific word like 'verbose' belong?

Tags: vocabulary

How does one determine the reading level to which a specific word belongs? For example, I want to use the word 'verbose' in some software. So, if I want to determine if it is appropriate to use the word based upon the users of the system, is there a web site where I can enter the word and get feedback?

Comment: I know that Unix shell scripts like `tar` list a `-v Verbose` option when you invoke them using a `--help` flag, so they think it is accessible to their audience...

Comment: I agree: "verbose" is entry level jargon, in this context I think you can expect it.

Comment: What "reading level" are your users?  Are they native speakers at all?  Kids?  What age?

Comment: I am not sure this question is on-topic, here. The question is not about English, but about which website could be used to know if a word should be used for a specific audience.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, I interpret the question as "how do I determine the reading level of a word?", and the OP is expressing an idle wish that this task were as easy as plugging the word into a magic machine somewhere on the internet.

Comment: I like the idea of being able to ascertain the reading level of a particular word or phrase.  I work with many non-native English speakers, and often find myself hitting the backspace key to undo what I just wrote to look for a simpler way to explain myself.

Comment: Then again, command line Unix is not reputed for its user friendliness, and its audience is mostly IT personnel, not general public.

Comment: Note that when it comes to non-English speakers, "difficult words" may not be those you would expect. This is particularly the case with French speakers as a significant portion of "complex English words" are in fact French words and thus easier for a French audience than seemingly "simple" words. Case in point, "verbose" is "verbeux" in French. In context, it should not be too hard to understand.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Sylverdrag. Unix commands have very little bearing on what is accessible to wide audiences. :-) (I say this as a happy user of several Unix systems myself.)

Comment: There's Google, if you trust their new [reading level feature](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Web%20Search/thread?tid=60e0869f5f9fad86&hl=en). It's meant to show the reading levels of websites rather than words, but you can get an idea by searching for the phrase and checking the reading level distribution of the results.  "verbose" gives [71% hits classified as "intermediate"](http://www.google.no/search?q=verbose&hl=en&tbs=rl:1)  reading level.
At least [some people seem to like it](http://www.problogger.net/archives/2011/02/01/use-google-reading-level-to-improve-your-blog-message/).

Comment: `verbose` was just an example. The actual use of the word `verbose` was in a discussion wherein the hearer did not know the meaning of the word. `verbose` in this case is not intended to be used in the software but the user's reaction triggered the question about reading level.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to your question, but there are many reading level indicators. Two of the most popular are the Flesch-Kincaid (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flesch-Kincaid_Readability_Test) and the Coleman-Liau (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coleman-Liau_Index). Microsoft Word has a built-in feature to calculate these statistics (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/display-readability-statistics-HP005189601.aspx?CTT=3)

Comment: I think this question is probably Too Localised, but [here's](http://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/common-words-5000.htm) a useful list of the 5000 most common words in English. *Verbose* doesn't appear there, which makes it less common than, say, *plaintiff, stereotype, diplomat, sustainable,* etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers And if you investigate the source of that list you get this: [wordfrequency page at BYU corpora](http://www.wordfrequency.info/).

Comment: @StoneyB: I think people should find better ways of monetising such knowledge - all you can get from that site for free is the 5000-word list I already linked to.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, somebody has to pay for the work; if the taxpayers/legislators won't, the users have to. And it's pretty damn cheap--compared the cost of an average academic monograph or graduate-level textbook.

Comment: @StoneyB: That's one point of view. Personally, I think far too much "academic" information is only accessible on a paid basis. Most of the revenue thus generated goes to a totally useless layer of parasites, much as it does/did in the music industry.

Comment: The scowl database http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/ also ranks words by difficulty level. "Verbose" is level 20, http://394ec01c0d122f63ebd7f0ce82413c15.scowl.db.barrycarter.info/ the second lowest level.

Comment: Another way to use wiktionary to find reading level. Visit the word, then click "what links here": http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere/verbose If you scroll down a bit, you'll see a link to http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Frequency_lists/PG/2006/04/20001-30000 which further shows its one of the 22401st-22500th most popular words in the language.

Comment: Datayze.com analyzes words “to predict audience familiarity and provide insights as to how the use of the word may affect readability metrics.” https://datayze.com/word-analyzer.php?word=verbose

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how to check "reading level" per se, but you can substitute for it by checking the usage frequency of individual English words online.

For instance:

- [A sample of the the top 60,000 lemmas from the Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](http://www.wordfrequency.info/files/entriesWithoutCollocates.txt)
- [Wiktionary Frequency lists](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aFrequency_lists)

The assumption here being that the more common words are more likely to be known to users than rarely used words.

According to a study on vocabulary*, high school grads will know approximately 12k word families and approx 17k word families by the time they complete college.

As such, you can use as a rule of thumb that any word past the 12k mark in frequency rating can be considered to be challenging for most users. (with of course of a lot of exceptions)

Also, keep in mind that while some words are commonly used, some definitions of these words can be very rare, making them likely to be misunderstood. In my opinion, the most challenging words of the English language are small common words such as "to", "as", "in", etc. which can have 10 - 30 different definitions.

Checking frequency is a negative test: If the word is not frequently used, you can safely assume that it will stump some of your readers, but it does not guarantee that a word frequently used will be easy enough either.

This is a great question, by the way. I find that one of the most neglected areas of software documentation is the definition of terms used and what they really mean in the context of the software.

* E.B. Zechmeister, A.M. Chronis, W.L. Cull, C.A. D'Anna and N.A. Healy, Growth of a functionally important lexicon, *Journal of Reading Behavior*, 1995, 27(2), 201-212 (Referenced in [Wikipedia's article on Vocabulary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocabulary).

Answer (score 4):

There's an (old — 1971) book called the *Living Word Vocabulary* that gave reading levels for different words. In it, "verbose" is given a score of 12–72%, which means that on a multiple-choice test, 72% of 12th graders could identify the correct meaning of "verbose".